# Query Google Spreadsheets select Min and Max dates as Column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a large row data sheet with several dates by company, and I need to calculate at column level the leadtime (max date - min date).

Raw Data Source:

| Data 1 | Date |
| --- | --- |
| name 1 | 1/1/2018 |
| name 1 | 1/2/2018 |
| name 2 | 1/3/2018 |
| name 2 | 1/5/2018 |
| name 2 | 1/1/2018 |
| name 2 | 1/2/2018 |
| name 2 | 1/3/2018 |

Expected Query Result:

| Data 1 | Min Date | Max Date | Lead Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name 1 | 1/1/2018 | 1/2/2018 | 30 days |
| name 2 | 1/1/2018 | 1/3/2018 | 60 days |

Answer (score 0):

```
=query(range;"Select A,min(B), max(B) group by A label min(B) 'Min Date', max(B) 'Max Date' ")
```